# CSV created with Python is blank

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

**This question was answered/resolved in the comments section.**

I am a noob to Python and I wrote the code below thinking it would copy all the rows with "NY" as the state in the state field/column to a new csv file called "Output.csv".

```
import csv

f = open(r'C:\Users..\input.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
output = open("C:...\Output.csv",'w')
fieldnames = ['firstScan', 'FinalScan', 'City', 'State', 'cld', 'daydiff']
writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',')

for row in reader:
    if row['State'] == 'NY':
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Everything runs fine but the output csv is completely blank. The first tab is named "Output" but the sheet is blank. If I have it output to txt, that is blank as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'll bet the issue is that you aren't closing your file. You should **always use a `with` statement** and then you won't have to remember to close your file.

Comment: As @juanpa.arrivillaga wrote, you don't close the file. It might be buffered; and the buffer never gets full or flushed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Where do I put the {with} statement?

Comment: Check out the [many examples in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: @JohnMinze. Or just put `output.close()` at the end.

Comment: @ekhumoro That worked perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
import csv

with open('C:/Users/felasniper/Desktop/input.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    output = open("C:/Users/felasniper/Desktop/Output.csv", 'w')
    fieldnames = ['firstScan', 'FinalScan', 'City', 'State', 'cld', 'daydiff']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',')

    for row in reader:
        if row['State'] == 'NY':
            writer.writerow(row)
```